# How to make an excel table that automatically sends email to someone on his birthday?

Tags: email, excel, outlook, excel-formula, vba

I need to write a formula that recognizes when someone's birthday is and trigger www.zapier.com.]

I have a birthday-recognition formula that creates a "send email" hyperlink, but I need it to be automatically sent (and delayed to 10am) non-interactively. I also did something in VBA but I only managed to write code that sends that message to 1 person.

Here's the working birthday-recognition formula. Client names are in column C8:C100, emails are in D8:D100, DOBs are in E8:E100 and the "send mail" hyperlinks are in F:100.

```
=IF(TEXT(E13;"d.m")=TEXT(TODAY();"d.m");HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D13&"? subject="&$D$2&"&body="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($E$3;"$";C13);"@";$D$4);"pošalji čestitku");"")
```

"pošalji čestitku" = send mail (croatian language)

VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

POŠALJIROĐENDANSKEČESTITKE

End Sub

Public Function POŠALJIROĐENDANSKEČESTITKE()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

 Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 olMail.To = Cells.Range("D8:D1000")

 olMail.subject = "Sretan rođendan"

 olMail.Body = "Poštovani," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Želimo Vam sretan rođendan"

& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Sve najbolje," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "svinaweb"

 olMail.Send

End Function
```

This code just sends the message to one email when I click on the command button, but as I said I want it to be sent to every person that has a birthday today and to delay the sending of the emails to 10am instead of midnight.

I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Try to put the code into a code block in your question, as it's very hard to read it otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please avoid repeating the same information over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class returns a Recipients collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item.

The [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) class provides the the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866951.aspx) method to create a new Recipient object and add it to the Recipients object. The [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703.aspx) property returns or sets the type of recipient. It can be one of the following [OlMailRecipientType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865653.aspx) constants: olBCC, olCC, olOriginator, or olTo.

So, you can send the single email to all people. You just need to add them to the Recipients collection. Or, if you need to have individual message bodies, you can create separate email messages.

The [DeferredDeliveryTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869452(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class allows to set a Date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

Comment: Hi @Eugene  I'm sure you just wrote me a solution to my problem, but I don't know exactly how to use these commands.  Please can you write me a VBA code you would use to do what I'm trying to do? These commands you suggested don't mean much to me beacuse I don't know how to correctly use them..